# How to get value based on a fixed interval for a huge database

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have an excel spreadsheet that has random numbers from 10 to 1500. What I want to get is that a row that gives 0 for any number up to 60 and from 61 onwards 0.5 for every 30 increment.

The desired result looks like this:

```
Numbers - result
11          0
56          0
60          0                     -- up to 60 zero
61          0.5
82          0.5
90          0.5                   -- 90 is 0.5 but 91 is 1
91          1
110         1
120         1
121         1.5
156         2                     -- 121 to 150 it is 1.5 and from 151 to 180 it is 2 and so on
```

I know it is a very simple formula that can help me over here. Please give me the formula without VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image]

Formula in B1 and drag down:

```
=IF(A1<61;0;INT((A1-31)/30)*0,5)
```